# Why converting varchar field to date is not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
    Select v.VendorCode VendorCode, V.VendorName
        where
        vi.Vendor_ID= 154 
        and 
        vi.Company_ID= (Select CompanyID from Company where CompanyID= '2')
        AND 
        (   Cast(vi.InvoiceDate as date) between Cast('3/1/2011' as date)
            AND cast('3/29/2018' as date)
        )
```

when I include the date part.. it doesn't return result. **InvoiceDate** is saved as **varchar** in table and is saving dates like `1/22/2019`.

I cannot change the type becuase it's the legacy database and has to be changed in thousand places.

Comment: "I cannot change the type becuase it's the legacy database and has to be changed in thousand places." - could you add a Computed Column instead?

Comment: **Never use** `CAST` or `CONVERT` to convert text to dates without specifying the exact format via the `style` parameter. For `MM/dd/yyyy` formatted dates the `style` value is `101`, so you should always use `CONVERT( date, '3/29/2018', 101 )`. This is because the culture/locale settings for a SQL query often depend on client-side configuration - so if I run the same query from my en-GB computer it will give me incorrect results or errors. This page has a reference of `style` values: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get an error? If you are expecting **1/22/2019** to be returned it won't because it is after your ending date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be able to change the data *in the database*, but you can at least get in the habit of using proper date formats for your queries.

First, use convert with format `101` for the conversion.  Use `try_convert()` if anyone got the date wrong.

Second, use `'YYYYMMDD'` or `'YYYY-MM-DD'` for date constants:

```
try_convert(date, v.InvoiceDate, 101) between '20110301' and '20180329'
```

Finally, you can add a computed column, so you can start to migrate to better code:

```
alter table v add InvoiceDate_Date as (try_convert(date, vi.InvoiceDate, 101));
```

Then you can write the logic as:

```
InvoiceDate_date between '20110301' and '20180329'
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug, try to see what the DBMS sees when filtering by date:

```
Select
    v.VendorCode
    , v.VendorName
    , cast(vi.InvoiceDate as date) as InvoiceDate
    , cast('3/1/2011' as date) as FromDate
    , cast('3/29/2018' as date) as ToDate
from ...
where
    vi.Vendor_ID = 154 
    and vi.Company_ID= (Select CompanyID from Company where CompanyID= '2')
```

Comment: "`Select CompanyID from Company where CompanyID= '2'`" - uhhhhh...

Comment: @Dai - Just copying the original clause. It's actually not identical to `vi.Company_ID=2` as there might not be such a company, in which case the subquery evaluates to null. But I suspect it's just the remnant of playing around with a proper condition for debugging purposes.